# Pass multiple arguments in a shell variable to find

Tags: bash

I have variables that contains find arguments, for example

```
args='-name a*'
args2='-name a* -o -name b*'
```

If I just do `find $args`, bash will expand the globs, so if I had a file named `apple` in the current directory the command would be equivalent to `find -name apple`. So I tried quoting the globs:

```
args='-name "a*"'
```

Now, `echo find $args` outputs `find -name "a*"`, which seems like what I want. However, the quote `"a*"` isn't expanded, so `find` is looking for filenames that start with a double quote.

How can I achieve the equivalent of `find -name "a*"` typed on the command line while storing the args in a variable?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Use an array rather than a plain variable: `args2=(-name 'a*' -o -name 'b*')` and `find "${args2[@]}"`